# How to render example source code from noSql database?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, backbone.js, syntax-highlighting

I've googled this loads and am sure there is an obvious way that I'm missing, but..does anyone know how to approach rendering example source code that is kept in a noSql database?

I am writing a javaScript blog site and want to show example code rendered from backbone templates whose models are populated from a mongoDB database.

Most of the google results offer a variety of syntax highlighting pulg-ins, but how would I format the code to preserve indentation etc as the code will be flat in a JSON object.

I'm thinking tables may be a key but I'm unsure if I'm reinventing the wheel here.

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in MongoDB can store any special characters like line-breaks, tabs or multiple spaces. When you store some program sourcecode as a string in a document, it should look the same when you retrieve the document.

Comment: Yeah, that is the only method I can think of but I was hoping there was a way to keep it a bit "dryer" by finding/creating a way of parsing the example code on rendering and applying indentation dynamically.  I would code this up if there is nothing like this yet but didn't want to do that if more experienced coders have already tread that path and done it better than i would be able to :) 
Thanks for answering :D

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need something to access the database and returns back that to the backbone.js client.

You can use a [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) server with the [MongoDB Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) if you prefer javascript.

You may want to try some node.js packages such as Express and Mongoose.

If this is a small project, just to learn how everything works, that's ok. Otherwise you might want to consider looking into how to display only the Blog Text by backbone.js, and separating the View from the Data. So if you want to change the CSS or they style of the blog you don't need to update (every single blog post document on mongo)

Comment: Thanks for answering :D yeah, im using a node.js server with express and mongoose doing the trekking to MongoHQ for my data. Im using require.js to load up the backbone models etc.  I am trying to loosely couple the view from the data as much as possible which is why im shying away from "hard coding" the example code and keeping it "dry".
I guess the only way i can see is adding DOM elements with classes in the mongo document and adding styling to create indentation etc on the code. It just felt a bit "wet" hahah, thanks again.

Comment: see this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110431/getting-started-with-mongodb-node-js-and-express
or this older [tutorial](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb)

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to suggest these but, I'm pretty good already with node/express/mongo/jade/etc. 
The bit that is slowing me down is that: when including example souce code in a blog, I need to format with indentation.  This isn't the case with an average "narrative blog". SO, It is really: how do i flat pack source code, so that it will automatically render in an indented way when backbone renders the model->document?

Comment: do i need to do somehting like this: 
   <pre><code><table class="code"><tbody> <tr><td>var</td><td> multiply = function(<span class="args"> arg1</span>,<span class="args"> arg2</span> ){</td></tr> <tr><td></td><td>return<span> arg1</span> * <span>arg2</span> ;</td> </tr> <tr><td>}</td> </tr>  <tr></tr></tbody></table></code></pre>